# how to create text style like in given image in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-ui

[image]

how to add shadow inside the text in flutter,
if you have any solution please let me know

Answer (score 1):

sadly in flutter there is no possible way to make an inner shadow with text widgets like that...you can try a few things though

**1. use a pre-made image with the text effect**
first get a high quality image, identify the image location with pubspec.yaml:

```
  assets:
- lib\images\textwithinnershadow.png
- images/a_dot_ham.jpeg
```

*note: they are more likely in line 62 and they are placed as comments...so remove the # at the start*

and then adding it to the main dart file you are working with simply like that

```
Container(
  child: Image.asset('lib/images/textwithinnershadow.png')
```

**2.create an illusion with a container**
there is a way to create an illusion of the effect in a container using boxshadow and gradients...here is a video by Mitch Koko explaining how to do it
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oTYDD3nZ-ZA

Comment: yes  i tried but value will change dynamically how I can manage this for every minute and hour I think this is not the right way